# Get All IDs Of A Post Type Using WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, id, post-type

I am trying to get a list of a custom post type's IDs using WP_Query, but it is returning undesired result, which is a memory leak and stuck browser.

Here is the code I use:

```
    $the_query = new WP_Query("post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1&field=ids");    
    if ($the_query->have_posts()) {
      while ($the_query->have_posts()){
         echo get_the_ID();
      }
    }
```

It makes my browser infinitely trying to load the page. May be somebody know what's wrong with the code above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `the_post()` function call in the loop. Just add

```
$the_query->the_post();
```

in your loop. Apart from that, your loop should work

### EDIT

You should also not forget to reset your postdata after the query is done

Comment: aw, seem a noob's mistake. but I now get a bunch of this kind of message `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in X:\xxxx\xxxxxxxxxxxx\wp-includes\query.php on line 4601`. What would be another problem?

Comment: I think that you might have misplaced the `the_post()` function call. I cannot see anything in your code that would suggest the issue. All seems fine

Comment: that's alright now, just another mistake that I didn't noticed, I shouldn't add `s` to the `field` argument's key.

Comment: Ag crap yes, I also missed that. Glad you found it. Enjoy ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I know you want solution "using WP_Query", but why not use `get_posts()` for this?

```
$posts_ids = get_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=-1&fields=ids');
// $posts_ids is now an array of IDs
echo implode(',', $posts_ids); // prints: 123, 124, 125, 126, ...

// or

foreach( $posts_ids as $id ) {
    echo $id;
}
```

Comment: `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` to return an array of posts, so the odds remain the same whether you are using one or the other. The main difference is, `get_posts` return only the `$posts` property from the query object and not the complete query object, and `get_posts` breaks pagination legally by passing `no_found_rows=true` to `WP_Query`

Comment: Yeah, I know, but if the goal is "retrieve only IDs", than with `WP_Query` you have to `the_post()` it, and then `wp_reset_postdata()` it ... so two more steps, that can be forgotten ;)

Comment: is it faster than using `WP_Query`?

Comment: I don't think so. It's fewer lines of code ... and _maybe_ it's more efficient, so about few miliseconds faster, too. Nothing you will notice.

Comment: This works by coincidence. `get_posts` has only `array` as a valid input type in its [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/). It works by coincidence since `get_posts` passes the input to `wp_parse_args` but I would warn against using a WP function counter to its documentation.